# How to use ngFor together with the flipping card in angular

Tags: angular

Here Im trying to use ngfor to generate some flip cards. But they cards dont start a new line and ovcerlaps in the first line. Here actually got 4, but the 4th overlap with the 1st card.
I think this is related to the css position, but dont know how to solve this.

Someone could have a look? thanks!!!

this is the link for flipping card.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A5rB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbg3c8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ohhh I see, then i think there might be a problem with the classes i used!!
Thanks man!